# Query and modify list of children with arbitrary positions

Tags: postgresql, database-design

With the following schema in mind:

```
parent (
  parent_id
  child_id
)
```

```
child (
  parent_id
  child_id
  position
)
```

I try to design a schema that allows me to retrieve a list of children, where children can be ordered arbitrarily. Adding a child to a parent is the same as appending it to the end of list, with its position equal to the maximum position of all positions for a given parent + 1. One should also be able to re-position a child with respect to its siblings, here, by changing the position columns of multiple child entries. One should also be able to delete a child, with their respective positions staying unchanged.

Querying the children of a given parent according to their position would follow this type of query:

```
select child.* 
  from child 
  where child.parent_id = $1 
  order by child.position asc;
```

I wonder whether this sort of schema would be adequate, as any manipulation, whether insertion of a child, or changing the position of a child, becomes quite complicated, as it involves querying/modifying existing records at first. Should we instead place the position data onto the parent table, as an array of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two common ways of modelling hierarchical date in relational database - [the adjacency list and the nested set.](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) Joe Celko has an entire book dedicated to this.

Your proposed model is based on the adjacency list. It's intuitive, but often hard to work with - retrieving a hierarchy requires recursive queries, and updates/inserts can be complicated.

The alternative is the nested set - which is *much* more efficient when querying, and inserts/updates are simpler (though do require more records to be modified).